Issue passing multiple variables inside of a data-href
I'm trying to pass 3 values through this data-href to the function linkpatientdevice. Though when I try to pass more than one variable as a parameter I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script". I can hard code values to pass, but when I try to input any variable as a second or third parameter it returns that error.
var patientDeviceVal = {id: d.USERID, device1: 'null', device2: 'null'};

... data-href=' + 'javascript:linkPatientDevice(' + patientDeviceVal.id + ',' + patientDeviceVal.device1 + ');' + ...

I am expecting the second value to be the string null but I just get the error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script.

I have also tried string literals using \ and ${} to the same result.

I think we need more context. How are you building whatever element data-href is part of? I'm thinking javascript:...may not be the best way to call this function. And how are you using the data-href attribute?

Please show actual code, not these little excerpts.

You should have quotes around the value of data-href. Using a template literal will make this easier.

I feel like the quotation marks may be a problem here. You're using all single quotes, both to indicate the attribute value, and concatenating strings.


The error seems to come from wrong syntax in the data-href attribute. Certainly I would use data-href="..." and then ' to delimit strings in the attribute value (in place of the dots). Or vice versa.
Assuming you have declared the function linkPatientDevice() and it is available in the page (script is linked, or the function declared directly in <script> tag), you should place the javascript:linkPatientDevice(...) in a href attribute of <a> tag. That way, click on the link will trigger the function. Click on any element/tag with data-href attribute does not per se (without event listener) trigger anything.
See Difference between href and data-href in anchor tag in html.

Notes:
Inline syntax (javascript:function... in a tag's href) is not viewed favorably, because it is very difficult to debug. Far better to bind the call with event listener: e.g. plain javascript, jQuery.
Custom data attributes (data-*) are used to pass data from html (possibly generated by backend) to the event listener function. That way you do not have to write the function with the parameters (linkPatientDevice(id, device1, device2)) into html. Instead you call the function you have declared inside the event listener, and pass to it the required values from the dataset object. e.g.:
<div data-id="your ID value" 
     data-device1="your device1 value" 
     data-device2="your device2 value"
>
   click here
</div>

and in the event listener
(event) => {
   const { dataset } = event.target;
   linkPatientDevice(dataset.id, dataset.device1, dataset.device2); 
}

See MDN dataset.
